# Can I get JSON format data from ACS?

Tags: azure, acs

When I began to read the ACS 2.0 document, I realized, ACS integrate with claim based authentication.
So if I don't want to use claim in my application, how should I get data in SWT or JSON format?

Does anyone have an example of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most simple solution: switch ACS to use SWT token, configure your app to save bootstrap token and use them in your way
web.config:

```
<system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true">
```

Application:

```
var claimIdentity = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
if (claimIdentity == null)
{
    return;
}

BootstrapContext bootstrapContext = claimIdentity.BootstrapContext as BootstrapContext;
SecurityToken token = null;
//you must configure SWT token handler in web.config or set up 'em manually like
SecurityTokenHandlerCollection handlers = FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers;
//here is a bug in 4.5 cause a bootstrapContext.SecurityToken disappear sometimes. 
//http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2012/11/30/using-the-bootstrapcontext-property-in-net-4-5.aspx
if (bootstrapContext.SecurityToken != null)
    {
        token = bootstrapContext.SecurityToken;
    }
else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bootstrapContext.Token))
    {
        token = handlers.ReadToken(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(bootstrapContext.Token)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You configure the [token format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185906.aspx#BKMK_3) of the relying party to specify the format of the token issued by ACS. I recommend you review [Protocols Supported in ACS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185948.aspx), as you will be leveraging one of these protocols if you plan on integrating your application (relying party) with ACS. [Token Formats Supported in ACS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185950.aspx) covers the differences in the token formats and help you decide which is the best choice for your relying party.

Regardless of the token format (SAML, JWT, SWT) you choose to have issued, your relying party will be responsible for validating the web token and extracting the asserted claims when making authorization decisions.